# ESS cannot find documentations in specified packages

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I am using ESS(12.04), emacs(23.3.1) and R(2.14.1). It works very well except that I cannot open a help from R if the function is inside an package. For example:

In R(iESS mode)

```
> ?ls
```

I will get the help file, but if I run

```
> ?caTools::runmean
```

I will get "No documentation for 'caTools::runmean' in specified packages and libraries:
you could try '??caTools::runmean'".

I am sure that this is a problem of ESS because that if I run the command in R Console, it works perfectly fine. The following is the part of my .emacs file that relevant to ESS:

```
;; ESS mode
(require 'ess-tracebug)
(add-hook 'ess-post-run-hook 'ess-tracebug)
;; Set to open help in a webbrowser
;;(setq inferior-ess-r-help-command "help(\"%s\", help_type=\"html\")\n")
;;(setq ess-help-own-frame t)
;; ESS-R_object-tooltip
;(require 'ess-R-object-tooltip)
;; Auto completion for R
;;(require 'ac-R)
;;(make-local-variable ac-ignore-case)
```

I have comment out most of my customization trying to identify the problem without luck. If anyone have any comments or suspects, please kindly point it to me. It has been bothering me for a while. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might try upgrading R and Emacs.

Comment: After update of both, the problem is still there. I wonder if this also happens to the others or only to me?

Comment: Probably not related, but did you happen to change your default pager? E.g., `options(pager="less")` might clash ESS.

Comment: I am not sure what pager is but I do not think I changed it. I am using windows 7. Besides of what has shown above, I cannot even use ??runmean either. After upgrade, both of them get a simplified version of error message: No document for 'whatever my input is'.

Comment: BTW, this is definitely new. After the update, I notice now I can first load the library of "caTools" and then use ?runmean. I will stick to this for now until I find better solutions.

Comment: `ls` is part of the base package, which means it is loaded by default, and its documentation is available to R and ESS. Optional add-on packages like `caTools` must be loaded before R or ESS can find their documentation. So I think this is normal. The only surprising thing is you seem to have been able to access the help files for caTools from R in the R Console without explicitly loading the package. This should only be possible if you have already loaded `caTools` in the console. Perhaps it is loaded automatically somehow?

Comment: You are probably right. I just test it and find that I can run runmean directly inside of R with the prefix 
  caTools:caTools::runmean(c(1,2,3,2),k =2)

Comment: But the same command in ess generates an error:  "Error: 'runean' is not an exported object from 'namespace:caTools'". So probably, the starting configuration is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updated to ESS version 12.09 and Emacs 24.2. The problem disappeared. I assume it is becomes some small bugs in ESS.